# SpresenseでUSBホスト機能を実現することは可能？

Tags: spresense, usb

SpresenseのUSB_DP(N1),USB_DM(P1)を使用して、外部回路を設けることでUSB HOSTを実現することは可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: コントローラチップと基板で自作を試している人は居るようです。[UsbHostShield for Spresense](http://yokozawa766.car.coocan.jp/UsbHostShield4Spresense_v10.html)

Comment: https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0 を移植して、Arduino用の汎用USBホストシールド2.0 を動かした実績ならあります。ICSPコネクタを取ったりSPIピンを差し替えたりと少々改造が要るので、ミニUSBホストシールド2.0の方が楽だったかなと思います。Spresense SDKが使用しているNuttXにもUSBホストドライバがあったので頑張ればSDKでもUSBホストが動かせそうな気はします（試したことないですが）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spresense のマイコン CXD5602 の[マニュアル](https://www.sony-semicon.co.jp/products/common/pdf/CXD5602GG_technical_manual.pdf) (PDF) によると USB 2.0 Device support とはありますが Host の記述はないので無理っス。 Host コントローラを外付けするのは非現実的っスね。

Answer (score 0):

このような商品を生産している会社がありますよ。

https://twitter.com/p_art_lab/status/1444422439396589571

> USBホスト基板
> SPRESENSE基板に重ねることで、USB Type-A端子を搭載することができます！
> （受注生産計画中）

受注生産のようですが、問い合わせれば入手できるかもしれません。
一般販売してもらえると良いのですが…。